# Errors and Exceptions looping

Tags: python

Hi I want to loop my program so that as soon as it hits Exceptions it restarts from the beginning !

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
...         break
...     except ValueError:
...         print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

How can I do this

Comment: Am not sure what you want to do here. The code snippet that you have pasted above seems to work as expected. It prints the error and loops back if given an incorrect value as input, and breaks on being given a legal number

Comment: The `break` statement is ending your `while True:` loop.  Either conditionally `break`, or remove the statement so that the program runs forever.

Comment: what do you define as beginning? the code snipped above works, and repeats until you have a valid number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to remove the `break` in your `try` statement. It's telling python to exit the while loop.

```
    try:
        x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print "Oops! That was no valid number. Try again..."
```